# covering query string variations of a window.location.href

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, location, comparison

Consider the following JS code:

```
if ( window.location.href == "https://teamtreehouse.com/signin" ) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

I need that the comparison operator will not only cover the exact URL, but also any possible variation of it with query strings and data coming after the phrase "signin".

How will you do that in JS? I know it should include regex but as linear learning is important for me, I would prefer waiting to my course on JS regex in the coming weeks and just ask here, in this special occasion.

Comment: so do not read the full url, window.location has other properties, check out the documentation. Other option is to also do not do a comparison, but check if the string contains it....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
/^https:\/\/teamtreehouse\.com\/signin/i
```

The `^` means "starting with", and the extra `\` characters are just to escape special characters inside the regex.

As per the comment by @epascarello, you should definitely use the "ignore-case" parameter, `i` (added above).

---

### Edit:

Use the `test` function:

```
(/^https:\/\/teamtreehouse\.com\/signin/i).test(window.location.href)
```

Comment: Should I had a constructor as well, or this is a case that negates the need in a constructor? (Sorry, I'm used to PCRE from Linux where I never wrote constructor to allow regex usage and I wait for a JS regex course).

Comment: Jonah, why is it important to wrap the original syntax in parenthesis and chain test(window.location.href) to it?

Comment: @sangoko I didn't understand your first question. What do you mean by "constructor"?
As for your other question, the syntax used here is just syntactic sugar; it actually creates an instance of `RegExp`, and is equivalent to: `new RegExp('^https://teamtreehouse.com/signin', 'i')`. That instance is just a JS object, so in order to test whether a given string matches that regex, you need to call the `RegExp`'s `test` function and pass the string as argument (you may leave out the parenthesis, they are not required, but it's just a bit more readable that way, IMO).

Comment: AFAIK a constructor in JS is a function that creates instances for classes but I might made a wrong association. Anyway, thanks for explaining this.

Comment: @sangoko Oh, I think I understood you question now. Yes, you can say that `RegExp` is a class, and you can create instances of that class by invoking the constructor: `new RegExp(...)`. As I said, the `/.../` syntax is just syntactic sugar over the constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check if some string contains something.

**Ex:**

```js
if (window.location.href.match("https://teamtreehouse.com/signin")){
    // Do something
}
```

---

Also you can use this `.host` & `.pathname` from [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)  object.

**Ex:**

```js
var link = window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
if (link === "www.teamtreehouse.com/signin"){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: If I understand correct, the match() method is some kind of a global regex that includes everything that starts with the original phrase and/or everything that ends with it?

Comment: @sangoko `match` if the `.href` contains this string `https://teamtreehouse.com/signin` whatever before/after it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ( /^[https:\/\/teamtreehouse.com/signin][\?[\.]+]?/.test(window.location.href)) {
    // do stuff...
}
```